# Data Filters vs. Query Activities - discrepancy between the two

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, filters

I'm noticing a discrepancy between running a data filter versus running a SQL query activity (containing the same logic).

Here's my data filter:
[image]

And, here's my query activity:
[image]

Finally, here are both DE's and their counts:
[image]

Any idea what might be going wrong?  I also tried to enclose the text values in my data filter with single quotes which did not help out.

Comment: The discrepancy is somewhere in where I exclude email addresses and "OriginationDepartmentName".  Removing both from both data filter and query produced the same count.  Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that when the SQL query runs, it excludes all records that have a blank value for an email address.  When the data filter executes, it includes blank values for email addresses.